# If I split coherent state light in half (by a beam splitter) are the 2 output intensities correlated?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, quantum-optics, coherent-states

From what I have been told and understand, if I use a simple beamsplitter to split coherent state light, I will obtain 2 coherent states as a result.

Are the intensities of these two output states correlated? I think the literature & theory supports that it should not be correlated (If it did, then it would be a ``two-mode squeezed state'').

But conceptually this is a bit confusing, shouldn't these intensities be correlated by energy conservation?

Comment: By correlated do you mean output (1) intensities plus output (2) intensity equals the input intensity?

Comment: @BillAlsept, you can't measure all three at once, but you can measure the two outputs and see if measuring a low intensity is correlated with a higher intensity on the other